# Bounded , monotone sequence - help with proof

Tags: real-analysis

> $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers
>
> > $\displaystyle b_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+.....+a_n}{n}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$
> >
> > > If $\{a_n\}$ is bounded and monotone
> > >
> > > > > > prove that $\{b_n\}$ is bounded and monotone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Since $(a_n)$ is bounded and monotone then it's a convergent series so by [Cesàro theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) the series $(b_n)$ is also convergent, hence it's  bounded.

Moreover, we have
\begin{align}b_{n+1}-b_n&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k\\
&=\frac{n\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}a_k-(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^na_k}{n(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{n\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k+na_{n+1}-(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^na_k}{n(n+1)}\\
\end{align}
and since $(a_n)$ is monotone so  $a_{n+1}\leq a_k$ or $a_{n+1}\geq a_k$ and in the both cases we have $b_{n+1}-b_n\leq 0$ or $b_{n+1}-b_n\geq 0$ respectively, hence $(b_n)$ is monotone.

Answer (score 0):

To start on a problem like this, you should probably start with the definitions. Do you know what bounded and monotone mean?

Let's consider the bounded situation for a moment. A sequence is said to be bounded if there exists some $A$ so that $|a_n| \leq A$ for all $n$.

You want to show that $b_n$ is bounded. So, just take a look at what $b_n$ is. By definition, you want to find a $B$ such that $ |b_n| = |\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i| \leq B$ for all $n$. Try using the triangle inequality on that expression to bring in the absolute, and then consider that $a_n$ is bounded.

Recall that since $a_i$ is monotone, we have that $a_i \leq a_{i+1}$ for all $i$, or alternatively maybe $a_{i+1} \leq a_i$ for all $i$. Without loss of generality, let's assume that $a_i \leq a_{i+1}$ for the moment and try to show that $b_i \leq b_{i+1}$. That means, $b_{i+1} - b_i \geq 0$ for all $i$. So, try subtracting them:

$b_{n+1} - b_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$

Remember that $a_i$ are monotonic. Try using that to help solve this problem. If you need more suggestions, just ask.

Comment: Thanks sir for help and I proved {bn} is bounded and I tried to do the same step like u did bn+1-bn and i didnt reach my target.

Comment: so could u please give me more details in last step.Thanks in advance